# "(1) stop, (2) drop, (3) and roll" or "(1) stop, (2) drop, and (3) roll"

Tags: formality, lists

Which is correct, formally speaking, or is either acceptable based on style and consistency?

Comment: I would use the second. "Correct" in general depends on which style guru you want to listen to.

Comment: The conjunction is **not** a part of item (3) and so has no business getting inside -- it's part of the sentence and so follows item (2). That's not about English, though.

Comment: What's that to do with style even?

Comment: I'd say it is bad form to use parenthetical numbers inside a sentence, rather than leading off a paragraph for each.

Comment: I believe the second one is a better way of putting it, especially while speaking.

Comment: SrJoven, the example was arbitrary, not the point I was asking, obviously. Oldcat, you not only also answered a question that I didn't ask, but ignored the one that I did. Kris, thank you for the useful response. I follow your logic about the list, but I am curious about how you think my question is not about "English Language and Usage."

Comment: Correct according to whom? Are you going to be penalized, shunned, looked down upon, for saying these things? It depends on the audience. There is a grammatical way of stating a numbered list, and assigning the number after *and* is the correct answer. Whether the steps actually require numbering is probably more important to formal speech (likely not unless the audience can't count/enumerate.)

Comment: Would your Q and its answer be any different if it were, say, in French? Why would the English language follow an idiosyncracy in this respect? It's applicable to any language, right?

Comment: No. It wouldn't. Yes, it would. Now, why should I only present problems that are present in the English language and in no other languages while excluding problems that are present in the English language and in other languages? Are you sure this site is meant to be operated so?

Answer (score 2):

> (1) stop, (2) drop, and (3) roll

is the correct phrase.  This is because *and* is a conjunction, and not part of step three.

Think about it this way:  what if there were four steps?  The first three steps stay the same, and then we add a fourth step:

> (1) stop, (2) drop, (3) roll, and (4) party!

you wouldn't have:

> (1) stop, (2) drop, (3) and roll, (4) and party!

You also see this when listing out steps in a bulleted or numbered format:

1. Stop,
2. Drop,
3. Roll, and
4. Party!

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the explanation. I'll have to say I agree with you.

Answer (score -3):

Surely this must depend on the context?

If I was explaining exercise manoeuvres, I would write it like this;
(1): Stop. (2): Drop. (3): Roll.

If it was part of a narrative then;
*stop, drop and roll.*

No matter what the context is, you definitely do not need a comma before *and* in this instance.

http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/020204whencommabfand.htm